# How to flat_map and split from an iterator of Strings

Tags: rust, ownership

Is there a way to make this work without switching to using `iter` instead of `into_iter`?

```
let strings: Vec<String> = vec!["1 2".to_string(), "3 4".to_string()];
strings.into_iter().flat_map(|str| str.split(" "));
```

The problem is

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `str`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:40
  |
3 |     strings.into_iter().flat_map(|str| str.split(" "));
  |                                        ---^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                                        |
  |                                        returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
  |                                        `str` is borrowed here
```

When using `iter` instead of `into_iter`, I get an iterator of references and everything works but I'd like to know if it's possible to make this work on an iterator of `String`s.

Comment: What do you want to have at the end? Owned or borrowed strings?

Comment: the next step is parsing them into integers using `.map` so it doesn't matter I guess

Comment: I advice you to fully understand the borrowing rules of Rust before doing something complicated, otherwise you will not be able to do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are doing those actions:

1. You are consuming your vector with `into_iter`
2. Thus, inside the closure, you are taking a `String` by value that you borrow with `split`
3. In your temporary iterator, you hold a reference to this string

Conclusion: you are trying to return a reference to a local variable.

To solve this issue, you must create owned strings from the split string, and collect them to not hold a reference anymore:

```
fn main() {
    let strings = vec!["1 2".to_string(), "3 4".into()];
    let result = strings.into_iter().flat_map(|str| str.split(" ").map(str::to_owned).collect::<Vec<_>>());

    println!("{:?}", result.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

In fact, this would be less costly to not consume the vector at first:

```
fn main() {
    let strings = vec!["1 2".to_string(), "3 4".into()];
    let result = strings.iter().flat_map(|str| str.split(" ")).map(str::to_owned);

    println!("{:?}", result.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and end up creating an iterator that take the ownership of the string, here is the code. Since you're splitting by space it should fit

```rust
struct Words {
    buf: String,
    offset: usize,
}

impl Words {
    fn new(buf: String) -> Words {
        Words { buf, offset: 0 }
    }
}

impl Iterator for Words {
    type Item = String;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<String> {
        let s = &(self.buf)[self.offset..];
        let left = s.chars().take_while(|x| x.is_whitespace()).count();
        let right = left + s[left..].chars().take_while(|x| !x.is_whitespace()).count();
        if left < right {
            self.offset += right;
            return Some(String::from(&s[left..right]));
        }

        None
    }
}
```

Here how I use it

```rust
fn read_file<'a>(buf: impl BufRead) -> impl Iterator<Item = String> {
    buf.lines().filter_map(Result::ok).flat_map(Words::new)
}
```